# Apple Push Notification locking iPhone 4s screen

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an app that used to accept push notifications without any issues but since I upgraded to a 4s, I'm noticing that sending a push while the app is not in the foreground locks my screen.  The moment I send the push, my phone's screen goes blank with a spinner and then the lock screen keyboard comes up.  Anybody have any idea why this is happening?  My friend who has a iphone 4 on ios4 seems to be getting the pushes fine.   This seems like a something that should not even be possible because it could be abused by rogue app developers

Comment: Had new iOS installed properly, I thing reinstall it once again and try.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that but I guess there is always that.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this myself.  This is what a normal alert looks like:

```
{
     "aps" : { "alert" : "This is the alert text", "badge" : 1, "sound" : "default" }
}
```

I was sending "sound":"" and got the exact same bug you were getting.  If you do not want to send a sound with your message, don't send the sound bit at all.

bad:
    {
         "aps" : { "alert" : "This is the alert text", "badge" : 1, "sound" : "" }
    }

good:
    {
         "aps" : { "alert" : "This is the alert text", "badge" : 1 }
    }

Comment: Nailed it bro!  Thank you so much.  It looks like they've stopped support for '' and null you're passing in the payload.   I didn't see any documentation for it but I guess it's probably not a bad idea given the serious size limitation on the payload.